# I want users to be able to select from an Admin populated drop-down field in a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I am new to building databases and am trying to learn asp.net MVC.

I am going to explain this the way I have it outlined in Excel.

> I have three tables:
>
> > Course(CourseID, Name) // I need to be able to add instructors
> >
> > Instructor(InstructorID, Name) // I need to be able to add new course names
> >
> > AppliedCourse(AppliedCourseID, CourseID, InstructorID, other misc fields) // I  need instructors to be able to apply to teach courses

Now using asp.net MVC 3 specifically, I know how to add a single table to a database that does not reference another table, but I want this web app to allow an instructor (after logged in) to 'apply to teach a course' where they will be confronted with a form.

> Within this form I want there to be the fields for the AppliedCourse table.
>
> > I want the Instructor to be limited in choosing the "CourseID" by having a drop down box that lists all the courses (by "Name") from the Course table.
> >
> > I want the InstructorID field to be auto-filled by the Instructor's logon name (which will be assigned in the Instructor table (i.e. InstructorID 1, Teacher One's Name).
>
> How do I do the above?

*I will (somehow) have an Administrator allow a User to apply to become an Instructor, at such point the user will be added to the Instructor table.  The Administrator will also add courses to the Course table as necessary.*

I understand how I can make a user able to fill out a form and have that data be input into a database and displayed/edited later (thanks to a plethora of online tutorials), but **I do not understand how to limit the user's input choice per cells on another table (i.e. the Instructor choosing from a list of courses in a drop down).**

I would prefer not to 'smash' something together, what would someone who knows what they are doing do in this situation?

Edit:

I'm thinking something like this will be used. . . (still fuzzy to me)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
{
  var db = new DatabaseName();
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Instructor
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                   {
                     Value = c.InstructorID.ToString(), 
                     Text = c.Name
                   });
  ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
  return View();
}
```

Comment: You're a bit unclear, but this seems like a very basic ASP.NET MVC question: "How do I populate a dropdown?" 

MVC is not at all wedded to a db implementation: Your databacking for the drop-down can come from anywhere...

Comment: Ok, how do I reference another table within a table?

Comment: So on the schema of the AppliedCourse table, you will set a foreign key from CourseId to the CourseId field of the Course table.

Comment: That will make it behave as if it is this:

AppliedCourse(AppliedCourseID, (CourseID, Name), InstructorID, other misc fields)

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApplyForCourseModel.cs

```
public ApplyForCourseModel
{
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

ApplyForCourseController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ApplyForCourse()
{
    var courses = dbContext.Courses.ToList();
    var model = new ApplyForCourseModel {InstructorId = 123, Courses = courses};
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ApplyForCourse(ApplyForCourseModel model)
{
    var appliedCourse = new AppliedCourse 
                            { 
                                InstructorId = model.InstructorId, 
                                CourseId = model.CourseId
                            }

    dbContext.AppliedCourses.Add(appliedCourse);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return View("Success");
}
```

ApplyForCourse.cshtml

```
@model MvcUniversity.Models.ApplyForCourseModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    Courses: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseId, 
                                   new SelectList(Model.Courses, "CourseId", "Name"),
                                   "-- Select Course --")

    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
}
```

This should give you a good starting block for the course application. The `ApplyForCourseModel` contains the `Id` of the `Course` and `Instructor` and a list of all possible `Course`s that can be applied for. You can obviously add other properties to this model.

The `ApplyForCourseController` create a new `ApplyForCourseModel` by using the `Id` of the `Professor` who is currently logged in and selecting every `Course` from the database and passes it to the view. The `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes determine what action to take when the page is visited or when the form is submitted (or posted).

Finally, the `ApplyForCourseView` displays the dropdown list containing the courses that can be applied for and contains a form to submit the application back to the controller.

Comment: The HttpPost and HttpGet parts of ApplyForCourseController.cs each have a public ActionResult named ApplyForCourse - this will not compile, how do name these appropriately?

Comment: @user1026898 Sorry I made a typo earlier, the second method should be `[HttpGet] public ActionResult ApplyForCourse(ApplyForCourseModel model) { ... }`. I have updated it in the above sample as well.